# cmake version changes after source command($PATH)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile

I have installed latest version of cmake 3.25 earlier i was using 3.12
now when i do `cmake --version` it shows `3.25` but there is one file which is using (`export PATH={some path}`) when I source that file `$PATH` env variable changes and when I run `cmake --version` it shows `3.12`

I am not getting why this is happening .why cmake version changes after I source that file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What Linux distribution do you use? Maybe you have two versons of CMake in different directories, e.g. one in `/usr/bin`, the other in `/usr/local/bin`. How did you install the CMake versions? From your distribution's software packages? From source? Show the output of `echo $PATH; type cmake` both before and after sourcing the file that modifies `PATH`.

Comment: You have multiple installations of `cmake` and changes in `PATH` exposes different installation. Use `whereis cmake` to find whch `cmake`'s are reachable by `PATH`.